# Android Error parsing XML: not well-formed and other Error

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

I am working on an application, in which i have a following xml. but when i try to clean/build my project the following errors occurs:

error:

```
Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)
android:text" associated with an element type "TextView" must not contain the '<' character
```

Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Hola!_Això_és_una_proba_per_el_treball_de_recerca"        
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks!

Comment: If this is really your xml, then yeah, it's pretty malformed. But I assume this is not really the whole xml?

Comment: Try to remove `!` from `@string/Hola!_Això_és_una_proba_per_el_treball_de_recerca`

Comment: It's all the activity_main.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't close `<TextView` so it is seeing the `<` from your root end tag as part of the `android:text`. Close the `TextView` tag with `/>`

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Hola!_Això_és_una_proba_per_el_treball_de_recerca"/>
```

You may need to clean your project and run again after doing this. In Eclipse

> Project --> Clean...

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the closing `/>`

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Hola!_Això_és_una_proba_per_el_treball_de_recerca" />
```

Comment: It should work . Check do you have any string with the name you mentioned "Hola!_Això_és_una_proba_per_el_treball_de_recerca" in string.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't closed the TextView with `/>`

Paste the following in place of your TextView

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Hola!_Això_és_una_proba_per_el_treball_de_recerca"/>
```